# WPF TreeView for a single list

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

How do I structure the xaml for a TreeView so that the output looks like this:

- Permanent

  - Teachers

    - Teacher 1 Name, Teacher 1 Parking Place number
    - Teacher 2 Name, Teacher 2 Parking Place number
  - Assistants

    - Assistant 1 Name, Assistant 1 Room
    - Assistant 2 Name, Assistant 2 Room
  - Buildings

    - Building 1 Name, Building 1 Room Count
    - Building 2 Name, Building 2 Room Count.
- Temporary

  - Teachers

    - Teacher 3 Name, Teacher 3 Parking Place number
    - Teacher 4 Name, Teacher 4 Parking Place number
  - Assistants

    - Assistant 3 Name, Assistant 3 Room
    - Assistant 4 Name, Assistant 4 Room
  - Buildings

    - Building 3 Name, Building 3 Room Count
    - Building 4 Name, Building 4 Room Count.

**Classes**

```
public class SchoolData
{
    public Contract Permanent { get; set; }
    public Contract Temporary { get; set; }
}

public class Contract
{
    public ObservableCollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Assistant> Assistants { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParkingPlaceNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Assistant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; set; } 
}

public class Building
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfRooms { get; set; } 
}
```

I think I need 6 separate `TreeView`s for each of the six lists that I want to display. I have tried the following, but all I get are object names and I do not get headers or heirarchical views.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Permanent.Teachers}" />
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Permanent.Assistants}" />
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Permanent.Buildings}" />
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Temporary.Teachers}" />
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Temporary.Assistants}" />
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Temporary.Buildings}" />
```

What should the xaml look like to achieve the needed tree view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Permanent" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Teachers" ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Permanent.Teachers}"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Buildings" ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Permanent.Buildings}"/> 
    </TreeViewItem>

    <TreeViewItem Header="Temporary" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Teachers" ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Temporary.Teachers}"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Buildings" ItemsSource="{Binding SchoolData.Temporary.Buildings}"/> 
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: That is close, but it only gives me two expandable nodes and the bottom child nodes just give the object type, but doesn't list the individual strings/ints of each teacher and building: 
- Permanent
  - Teachers
      TestProgram.Teacher
      TestProgram.Teacher
  - Buildings
      TestProgram.Building
      TestProgram.Building
Also, what do I do if the list is null?  I don't want the header to appear at all.

Comment: to get custom details for each type of object you need to define Itemtemplate in corresponding TreeViewItems. since template are used in two places, defines them in resources and then reference from tree: `<TreeViewItem Header="Teachers" ItemsSource={Teachers} ItemTemplate="{StaticResource teacherDataTemplate}"/>`

Comment: and if you have more complicated requirement which you didn't mention at all in the question - then do some research and if nothing helps, ask another question.

Comment: "what do I do if the list is null" - now that I think about it, it shouldn't be difficult to write a value converter, which convert null to Visibility.Collapsed, and everthing else to Visibility.Visible. and then you use that converter to bind TreeViewItem.Visibility like `<TreeViewItem Header="Teachers" Visibility="{Binding SchoolData.Temporary.Teachers, Converter={StaticResource Null2VisibilityConverterInstance}}"`

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking.  Thank you for your help.